# Targeting a string for deletion with grep, sed, awk (or cut)

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cut

I am trying to parse some logs to gain the user agent and account id per line.  I have already managed to pull the user agent and a string which contains the account id all on the same line.

The next step is to extract the account id from its longer string. I thought this would be fairly simple as I will know the start of the string and there are / slashes for the delimiter but the user agent also contains slashes and have varied number of fields.

The log file currently looks something like the following example but there are hundreds to thousands of lines to parse. Luckily I am working off a partition with plenty of space to spare.

```
USER_AGENT_PART         ACCOUNT_ID_Part_/plus/path/to/stuff/they/access

some user agent/1.3     KnownString1_32d4-56e-009f98/some/stuff/here
user/agent              KnownString1_12d3-345e-4c534/more/stuff/here
User/Agent cURL/1.5.0   KnownString2_12d34e56/stuff/things/stuff/stuff
one/User Agent/2.0      KnownString1_12d3_456e_7g8/more/random/stuff/stuff
```

So the goal is to keep the user agent part and the account id part and drop the path of the stuff they are accessing in the last string.  But I can't use / or spaces as general delimiters because many user agents have / and various amounts of spaces in their name.

Also, the different types of user agents is way more than this little sample I have here.  There are anywhere from 25 - 50 distinct types depending on the log. So it doesn't seem worth it to target the user agent and try to exclude it.

It seems the logical way to start is by targeting the part of the account ID which is a known string (KnownString1 or KnownString2) and grab everything from there (which is unknown numbers and letters with dashes) up until the first / of that account string.

Then I would delete the first / (In the account ID string) and everything after.  I expect I will need to do this in two passes to utilize the two known parts of the user IDs.

This seemed like it would be easy but I just can't wrap my head around how to start targeting that last string.  I don't even have a good example of something that is close to working because I don't know how to target the last string by delimiters without catching the same delimiters in the user agent part.

Any ideas?

Edit: Every line will have an account id that starts with one of two common KnownString_ in it but then is followed by a series of unknown digits and dashes until it gets to the first /. So I don't need to search for lines containing that before targeting the string.

Edit2: My original examples of the Account ID did not reflect there were letters mixed in with the numbers.

Edit3: Thanks to the responses from oguz ismail and kesubagu I was able to solve this using egrep. Looks like I was trying to make things more complicated than they were. I also realized I need to revisit grep as its capable of doing far more than what I tend to use it for.

This is what I ended up using which worked in one pass:

egrep -o ".+(KnownString1|KnownString2)_[^/]+" logfile > logfile2

Comment: Is the first field, e.g `^................   KnownString...` (up to the beginning of `KnownString...` a fixed width?

Comment: Thank you for replying. No unfortunately that first field length was no a fixed length.  But I was able to mix kesubagu and oguz ismail's responses into one that worked in a single pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
$ grep -o '.*KnownString[^/]*' file
some user agent/1.3     KnownString1_32d4-56e-009f98
user/agent              KnownString1_12d3-345e-4c534
User/Agent cURL/1.5.0   KnownString2_12d34e56
one/User Agent/2.0      KnownString1_12d3_456e_7g8
```

`.*` matches everything before `KnownString`, and `[^/]*` matches everything after `KnownString` until the first `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `egrep` with the `-o` option which will only output the part of that matches the provided regex, so you could do something like this

`cat test | egrep -o ".+(KnownString1|KnownString2)_[_0-9-]+"`

where the `test` file contains the input you've given, the output in this case was

```
some user agent/1.3     KnownString1_324-56-00998
user/agent              KnownString1_123-345-4534
User/Agent cURL/1.5.0   KnownString2_123456
one/User Agent/2.0      KnownString1_123_456_78
```

Comment: Wow. First of all thank you very much for responding.  This gets me so much closer.  It does in fact work according to what I specified. 

 Unfortunately,I  left out the fact that there were some letters mixed in with the numbers as well.I will edit original post reflect that.

So it doesn't work exactly as is for my real world case even though it got close. Hopefully I can use this as a starting point and adjust it to work.  I have been jumping between awk and sed tutorials all day looking for something that would work. Still have a lot to learn I guess. Will try to tweak it tomorrow.